# How do I search a Jar to see if it contains a class from the command line

Tags: java, class, jar, jms

What is the comand to determine if a class exists within a jar

I tried the following

```
java -jar TEST.jar -i . button
Ignoring unknown flag: -i
Ignoring unknown flag: .
Ignoring unknown flag: button

java.lang.NullPointerException
```

But obviously it did not work

Could someone please post an example of how to do this for

1> Th ecurrent directory

2> any subdirectory

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `jar tf` command and grep for the class you want:

`jar tf TEST.jar | grep Button`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the documentation of using Jar files on the command line.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

You can list the contents of the Jar on the command line using:

```
jar tf jar-file
```

However, assuming you are using a Java program to examine the contents, you can open the Jar by creating a JarFile object, then iterate through its entries:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html

In case it helps, Jar files are a specific type of ZipFile.  The only notable differences have to do with the Jar's manifest information.